# Toon shader with Texture. Can this be optimized?

Tags: c++, opengl, shader

I have managed to integrate [Nehe's Cel-Shading](http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/cel_shading/25001/) rendering with my Model loaders, and have them drawn using the Toon shade and outline AND their original texture at the same time. The result is actually a very nice Cel Shading effect of the model texture, but it is havling the speed of the program, it's quite very slow even with just 3 models on screen...

Since the result was kind of hacked together, I am thinking that maybe I am performing some extra steps or extra rendering tasks that maybe are not needed, and are slowing down the game? 
Something unnecessary that maybe you guys could spot?

Both MD2 and 3DS loader have an InitToon() function called upon creation to load the shader

```
initToon(){

    int i;                                                        // Looping Variable ( NEW )
    char Line[255];                                                // Storage For 255 Characters ( NEW )
    float shaderData[32][3];                                    // Storate For The 96 Shader Values ( NEW )
    FILE *In = fopen ("Shader.txt", "r");                        // Open The Shader File ( NEW )

    if (In)                                                        // Check To See If The File Opened ( NEW )
    {
        for (i = 0; i < 32; i++)                                // Loop Though The 32 Greyscale Values ( NEW )
        {
            if (feof (In))                                        // Check For The End Of The File ( NEW )
                break;

            fgets (Line, 255, In);                                // Get The Current Line ( NEW )

            shaderData[i][0] = shaderData[i][1] = shaderData[i][2] = float(atof (Line)); // Copy Over The Value ( NEW )
        }

        fclose (In);                                            // Close The File ( NEW )
    }

    else
        return false;                                            // It Went Horribly Horribly Wrong ( NEW )

    glGenTextures (1, &shaderTexture[0]);                        // Get A Free Texture ID ( NEW )

    glBindTexture (GL_TEXTURE_1D, shaderTexture[0]);            // Bind This Texture. From Now On It Will Be 1D ( NEW )

    // For Crying Out Loud Don't Let OpenGL Use Bi/Trilinear Filtering! ( NEW )
    glTexParameteri (GL_TEXTURE_1D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);    
    glTexParameteri (GL_TEXTURE_1D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

    glTexImage1D (GL_TEXTURE_1D, 0, GL_RGB, 32, 0, GL_RGB , GL_FLOAT, shaderData);    // Upload ( NEW )


}
```

This is the drawing for the animated MD2 model:

```
void MD2Model::drawToon() {
    float        outlineWidth    = 3.0f;                                // Width Of The Lines ( NEW )
    float        outlineColor[3]    = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };                // Color Of The Lines ( NEW )


// ORIGINAL PART OF THE FUNCTION


    //Figure out the two frames between which we are interpolating
    int frameIndex1 = (int)(time * (endFrame - startFrame + 1)) + startFrame;
    if (frameIndex1 > endFrame) {
        frameIndex1 = startFrame;
    }

    int frameIndex2;
    if (frameIndex1 < endFrame) {
        frameIndex2 = frameIndex1 + 1;
    }
    else {
        frameIndex2 = startFrame;
    }

    MD2Frame* frame1 = frames + frameIndex1;
    MD2Frame* frame2 = frames + frameIndex2;

    //Figure out the fraction that we are between the two frames
    float frac =
        (time - (float)(frameIndex1 - startFrame) /
         (float)(endFrame - startFrame + 1)) * (endFrame - startFrame + 1);


// I ADDED THESE FROM NEHE'S TUTORIAL FOR FIRST PASS (TOON SHADE)

    glHint (GL_LINE_SMOOTH_HINT, GL_NICEST);                // Use The Good Calculations ( NEW )
    glEnable (GL_LINE_SMOOTH);
    // Cel-Shading Code //
    glEnable (GL_TEXTURE_1D);                                    // Enable 1D Texturing ( NEW )
    glBindTexture (GL_TEXTURE_1D, shaderTexture[0]);            // Bind Our Texture ( NEW )

    glColor3f (1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);                                // Set The Color Of The Model ( NEW )

// ORIGINAL DRAWING CODE

    //Draw the model as an interpolation between the two frames
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    for(int i = 0; i < numTriangles; i++) {
        MD2Triangle* triangle = triangles + i;
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            MD2Vertex* v1 = frame1->vertices + triangle->vertices[j];
            MD2Vertex* v2 = frame2->vertices + triangle->vertices[j];
            Vec3f pos = v1->pos * (1 - frac) + v2->pos * frac;
            Vec3f normal = v1->normal * (1 - frac) + v2->normal * frac;
            if (normal[0] == 0 && normal[1] == 0 && normal[2] == 0) {
                normal = Vec3f(0, 0, 1);
            }
            glNormal3f(normal[0], normal[1], normal[2]);

            MD2TexCoord* texCoord = texCoords + triangle->texCoords[j];
            glTexCoord2f(texCoord->texCoordX, texCoord->texCoordY);
            glVertex3f(pos[0], pos[1], pos[2]);
        }
    }
    glEnd();

// ADDED THESE FROM NEHE'S FOR SECOND PASS (OUTLINE)

    glDisable (GL_TEXTURE_1D);                                    // Disable 1D Textures ( NEW )


    glEnable (GL_BLEND);                                    // Enable Blending ( NEW )
        glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA,GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);        // Set The Blend Mode ( NEW )

        glPolygonMode (GL_BACK, GL_LINE);                        // Draw Backfacing Polygons As Wireframes ( NEW )
        glLineWidth (outlineWidth);                                // Set The Line Width ( NEW )

        glCullFace (GL_FRONT);                                    // Don't Draw Any Front-Facing Polygons ( NEW )

        glDepthFunc (GL_LEQUAL);                                // Change The Depth Mode ( NEW )

        glColor3fv (&outlineColor[0]);                            // Set The Outline Color ( NEW )


// HERE I AM PARSING THE VERTICES AGAIN (NOT IN THE ORIGINAL FUNCTION) FOR THE OUTLINE AS PER NEHE'S TUT

        glBegin (GL_TRIANGLES);                                    // Tell OpenGL What We Want To Draw
        for(int i = 0; i < numTriangles; i++) {
        MD2Triangle* triangle = triangles + i;
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            MD2Vertex* v1 = frame1->vertices + triangle->vertices[j];
            MD2Vertex* v2 = frame2->vertices + triangle->vertices[j];
            Vec3f pos = v1->pos * (1 - frac) + v2->pos * frac;
            Vec3f normal = v1->normal * (1 - frac) + v2->normal * frac;
            if (normal[0] == 0 && normal[1] == 0 && normal[2] == 0) {
                normal = Vec3f(0, 0, 1);
            }
            glNormal3f(normal[0], normal[1], normal[2]);

            MD2TexCoord* texCoord = texCoords + triangle->texCoords[j];
            glTexCoord2f(texCoord->texCoordX, texCoord->texCoordY);
            glVertex3f(pos[0], pos[1], pos[2]);
        }
    }
        glEnd ();                                                // Tell OpenGL We've Finished

        glDepthFunc (GL_LESS);                                    // Reset The Depth-Testing Mode ( NEW )

        glCullFace (GL_BACK);                                    // Reset The Face To Be Culled ( NEW )

        glPolygonMode (GL_BACK, GL_FILL);                        // Reset Back-Facing Polygon Drawing Mode ( NEW )

        glDisable (GL_BLEND);    
}
```

Whereas this is the drawToon function in the 3DS loader

```
void Model_3DS::drawToon()
{

    float        outlineWidth    = 3.0f;                                // Width Of The Lines ( NEW )
    float        outlineColor[3]    = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };                // Color Of The Lines ( NEW )

//ORIGINAL CODE

    if (visible)
    {
    glPushMatrix();

        // Move the model
        glTranslatef(pos.x, pos.y, pos.z);

        // Rotate the model
        glRotatef(rot.x, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        glRotatef(rot.y, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        glRotatef(rot.z, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

        glScalef(scale, scale, scale);

        // Loop through the objects
        for (int i = 0; i < numObjects; i++)
        {
            // Enable texture coordiantes, normals, and vertices arrays
            if (Objects[i].textured)
                glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
            if (lit)
                glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
            glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

            // Point them to the objects arrays
            if (Objects[i].textured)
                glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, Objects[i].TexCoords);
            if (lit)
                glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 0, Objects[i].Normals);
            glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, Objects[i].Vertexes);

            // Loop through the faces as sorted by material and draw them
            for (int j = 0; j < Objects[i].numMatFaces; j ++)
            {
                // Use the material's texture
                Materials[Objects[i].MatFaces[j].MatIndex].tex.Use();


// AFTER THE TEXTURE IS APPLIED I INSERT THE TOON FUNCTIONS HERE (FIRST PASS)



                    glHint (GL_LINE_SMOOTH_HINT, GL_NICEST);                // Use The Good Calculations ( NEW )
                    glEnable (GL_LINE_SMOOTH);
                    // Cel-Shading Code //
                    glEnable (GL_TEXTURE_1D);                                    // Enable 1D Texturing ( NEW )
                    glBindTexture (GL_TEXTURE_1D, shaderTexture[0]);            // Bind Our Texture ( NEW )

                        glColor3f (1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);                                // Set The Color Of The Model ( NEW )



                glPushMatrix();

                    // Move the model
                    glTranslatef(Objects[i].pos.x, Objects[i].pos.y, Objects[i].pos.z);

                    // Rotate the model

                    glRotatef(Objects[i].rot.z, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
                    glRotatef(Objects[i].rot.y, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
                    glRotatef(Objects[i].rot.x, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

                    // Draw the faces using an index to the vertex array
                    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, Objects[i].MatFaces[j].numSubFaces, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, Objects[i].MatFaces[j].subFaces);

                glPopMatrix();
            }



                glDisable (GL_TEXTURE_1D);                                    // Disable 1D Textures ( NEW )


// THIS IS AN ADDED SECOND PASS AT THE VERTICES FOR THE OUTLINE


    glEnable (GL_BLEND);                                    // Enable Blending ( NEW )
        glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA,GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);        // Set The Blend Mode ( NEW )

        glPolygonMode (GL_BACK, GL_LINE);                        // Draw Backfacing Polygons As Wireframes ( NEW )
        glLineWidth (outlineWidth);                                // Set The Line Width ( NEW )

        glCullFace (GL_FRONT);                                    // Don't Draw Any Front-Facing Polygons ( NEW )

        glDepthFunc (GL_LEQUAL);                                // Change The Depth Mode ( NEW )

        glColor3fv (&outlineColor[0]);                            // Set The Outline Color ( NEW )

        for (int j = 0; j < Objects[i].numMatFaces; j ++)
            {
        glPushMatrix();

                    // Move the model
                    glTranslatef(Objects[i].pos.x, Objects[i].pos.y, Objects[i].pos.z);

                    // Rotate the model
                                    glRotatef(Objects[i].rot.z, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
                    glRotatef(Objects[i].rot.y, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
                    glRotatef(Objects[i].rot.x, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

                    // Draw the faces using an index to the vertex array
                    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, Objects[i].MatFaces[j].numSubFaces, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, Objects[i].MatFaces[j].subFaces);

                glPopMatrix();


        }

                glDepthFunc (GL_LESS);                                    // Reset The Depth-Testing Mode ( NEW )

        glCullFace (GL_BACK);                                    // Reset The Face To Be Culled ( NEW )

        glPolygonMode (GL_BACK, GL_FILL);                        // Reset Back-Facing Polygon Drawing Mode ( NEW )

        glDisable (GL_BLEND);

glPopMatrix();
}
```

Finally this is the tex.Use() function that loads a BMP texture and somehow gets blended perfectly with the Toon shading

```
void GLTexture::Use()
{
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);                                // Enable texture mapping
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0]);                // Bind the texture as the current one

}
```

EDIT----------------------------------------------------------------------------

Thank you all for your advice. Following the advice by Kos I have re factored the function in order to not use glBegin/End.... so I am storing the vertices in std::vectors after their positions have been calculated and then use glDrawArrays to read from the vector..... This is theoretically meant to be faster, but it's giving me a much lower framerate than before... Is this implemented correctly?

```
    for(int i = 0; i < numTriangles; i++) {
        MD2Triangle* triangle = triangles + i;
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            MD2Vertex* v1 = frame1->vertices + triangle->vertices[j];
            MD2Vertex* v2 = frame2->vertices + triangle->vertices[j];
            Vec3f pos = v1->pos * (1 - frac) + v2->pos * frac;
            Vec3f normal = v1->normal * (1 - frac) + v2->normal * frac;
            if (normal[0] == 0 && normal[1] == 0 && normal[2] == 0) {
                normal = Vec3f(0, 0, 1);
            }


            normals.push_back(normal[0]);
            normals.push_back(normal[1]);
            normals.push_back(normal[2]);

            MD2TexCoord* texCoord = texCoords + triangle->texCoords[j];
            textCoords.push_back(texCoord->texCoordX);
            textCoords.push_back(texCoord->texCoordY);

            vertices.push_back(pos[0]);
            vertices.push_back(pos[1]);
            vertices.push_back(pos[2]);
        }

    }


    glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

    glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 0, &normals[0]);
    glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, &textCoords[0]); 
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, &vertices[0]);



    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertices.size()/3);


    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);  // disable vertex arrays
    glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);

    vertices.clear();
    textCoords.clear();
    normals.clear();
```

Comment: You should visit http://codereview.stackexchange.com . This site is for specific programming questions.

Answer (score 2):

It's terribly inefficient. With just the information available from your code:

```
MD2Frame* frame1 = frames + frameIndex1;
MD2Frame* frame2 = frames + frameIndex2;
```

These 2 lines depending on how MD2Frame works either compute 2 key frames CPU side ( very very slow ), or offset into 2 pre computed key frames ( more likely ). What worries me is that all the information available suggests this is vertex animated, which at for example 24 fps will give you 24 * num vertices * size of per vertex data bytes of data per second of animation. What you should be doing is animate using bones and hardware skin your model.

EDIT: Noticed that it's in fact pointer arithmetic, so it's 99% certain it's the pre computed case.

The low hanging fruit here is using a VBO which you fill with the computed vertex info. Taking it a step further create 2 VBOs, one for each frame, bind them both to your vertex program, and then do the blending in the vertex program. Or, if you're going to be building anything which is somewhat demanding upon this code base, then look into animation with bones instead, which is a heck of a lot faster and more memory efficient.

EDIT: Clarification, there's use cases when vertex blending makes sense, so without knowing more about what you're trying to do I can't say more than: Look into if per vertex animation is actually the best solution for your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your input. For this programming assignment I am kind of required to be using keyframe animations, and MD2 is one of the easiest formats for it. The model animates at a very good speed without the toon code though!

Comment: less than 2000, MD2 format has that for vertex limit, so they're quite low poly.... but not all models are animated, the 3DS ones are static... The animation side of it hasn't really been a problem so far, jut this render effect is slowing down the thing cos I am cycling through all vertices twice as many times I imagine...

Comment: Thanks for the further info, everyone seems to agree that VBO is the way to go, what you suggest of having two separate ones, one for the Toon texture rendering and another for the outline edge rendering seems to be like a very smart way to go... I'll try and see if I can implement them with my moderate experience and get back with the results!

Comment: the second function which uses VBO seems to be quite slow though, could it be that it's because the two glDrawElement calls are using the same buffer object?

Comment: Most likely not, although I can only speculate. The easiest way would be for you to use a profiler ( google very sleepy if you're on windows, you'll be up and running in seconds ) & nvperfhud / gdebugger. If you didn't see much benefit VBOs, then it's more likely you're GPU bound.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look here:

```
 glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    for(int i = 0; i < numTriangles; i++) {
       // ...
            glNormal3f(normal[0], normal[1], normal[2]);
       // ...
            glVertex3f(pos[0], pos[1], pos[2]);
        }
    }
 glEnd();
```

This part is terribly inefficient, because you have several calls to the GPU driver *for each and every vertex of your model*. The correct approach would be to send it all using one draw call and vertex arrays, or - even better - preferably storing the geometry on the GPU using a vertex buffer object.

NeHe tutorials contain useful information, but are very outdated now; `glVertex` and `glBegin` and the family aren't really used nowadays.

Comment: That's informative, thank you! Another poster recommended me the same thing! I will look into implementing that with vertex buffer objects...Does anything terribly wrong stick out about the second function (3DS Models)? As the frame rate seems to be even lower when I only enable that one and not the first (MD2) one...

Comment: I have managed to re qork the function to remove the glBegin/End immediate drawing and re done it using sdt::vector containers and glDrawArrays....but it's proving to be even slower....could you have a look at the new function I posted above int he question to see if I've implemented it correctly? Thanks for your kind help!

Comment: Before we continue, let me just assure if the vectors aren't reallocated every frame? Are they defined outside of the rendering loop so that the memory buffers can be reused? That said, how does the performance change after you comment out all the `glDrawArrays()`? *(this should give us an indication if the CPU or the GPU is the limitation)*